# Overlay to dynamically show a list of values in ATG

Tags: jquery, ajax, overlay, atg

My requirement is as follows.
I am getting a list of addresses using a a custom droplet(ATG).
Now i need to show the list of addreses on an overlay.
First 5 addreesess and then when i click on next button, I need to show the next five addreeses.

The problem i am facing is whenever i am clicking next button, the whole page is getting reloaded and the next five addreeses are shown in normal page.

Thanks,
Neenu

Comment: What did you tried, where is your code? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This is the jsp page code which contains the overlay.
<div id="overlay" style="display: none;">
 <div id="invoiceAddresses" class="dialogue-container hidden" data-width="false" data-height="false">
 <dsp:droplet name="/atg/dynamo/droplet/Range">
  <dsp:param name="array" param="deliveryAddressList"/>
  <dsp:param name="howMany" value="6"/>
  <dsp:oparam name="output">
   <div><address>
    //values to display
   </address></div> 
  </dsp:oparam>
 </dsp:droplet> 
 </div>
</div>

custom droplet is used to fetch the list and passes the list to range droplet

Comment: req is like whenever i am clicking on abutton say"View all invoice address" I need to show 5 address in the first overlay  page..next five to shown when i click on the next button..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is less of an ATG-specific question and more of a general client-side/server-side code interaction question.

A standard form submit or a link will result in the whole page being replaced with the contents of the target URL - even if it is the same page. If you are displaying an overlay in response to an event on the page, then reloading the page will result in that state being lost

From your question tags it looks like you are using JQuery and want to use AJAX. Also, since you mention using a droplet, I assume you are using server-side page rendering with JSP and not REST/JSON.

The way overlays usually work is that the contents of the overlay is already rendered and sent to the browser. In the browser, the `div` containing the overlay is hidden using CSS. When the appropriate event occurs (e.g. clicking on a link or a button), then the overlay `div` is shown. The 'state' of the overlay - whether it is shown or hidden - is not held anywhere on the server. It exists only in the in-memory DOM of the client browser.

Now, it looks like you want to do pagination within the overlay. That is, you want to display addresses five at a time and be able to go forwards or backwards to display the next five or previous five. And you want the overlay to remain open.

This needs some careful planning of what should happen in the client, what should happen on the server and what should be the interactions between the two.

The general patterns to use here would be

**Option A** - Client-Side Pagination

Use the Droplet in the JSP to render *all* of the addresses in `div`s containing five addresses each and send to the client, and to use JavaScript and CSS (JQuery) to show the `div` containing the range you want to display and to hide the other ones.

This option uses JSP and Droplets on the server to render the page initially, but pagination is entirely client-side using JavaScript and CSS

This option has the advantage that pagination is very quick in the browser, but it has the disadvantage that it has to load all addresses from the repository and send them all to the browser

**Option B** - Server-Side Pagination

Create a new JSP page to represent *just* the contents of the overlay, and use a `Range` droplet (or related derivative) to render only the five addresses you want to display in it - using query string parameters to provide the `startIndex` etc.

In the client code, in response to the event when you want show your overlay, you should also make an AJAX `GET` request to this page fragment and replace the inner `div` of the overlay with the response. With JQuery, it would be something along the lines of `$("#overlay").load(".../.../addresses.jsp?startIndex=1")` where `overlay` is the id of the `div` representing the contents of the overlay.

The Next and Previous links in the address list should also make similar AJAX `GET` calls to this URL, with the appropriate startIndex.

This option has the disadvantage that it is (considerably) more complex, but allows you to only load the addresses you need and only send content to the browser when it is needed to be displayed.

Comment: I created a new jsp page to show the contents of the overlay-working fine.When i click on next link, i gave the following function
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
 $("#nextButtonNe").click(function(){
  alert("NextStart");
  var e = $('#nextStart').val();
  alert("NextStart"+e);
    $('.pagination-whoelList').load('/webshop/sweden/ricoh/inVoiceAddressOverlay.jsp?start='+e,function(responseTxt,statusTxt,xhr){   
   });
 });
});
Only once the function is getting called.

Comment: I dont understand why when i click again on the same link, the function is not getting called.

Comment: Chances are that your `<script>` tag is not being processed when you load the inner content of the overlay. When content is loaded with JQuery `load`, scripts are not interpreted, for security reasons. You will have to declare the function outside the `load`ed page and invoke it using `onclick=` or a `javascript:` URL on the Next link. Alternatively, you can use JQuery `getScript` to specifically load a script to be interpreted

Comment: yes.Used an onclick fn and it worked..used jQuery('<div tag of new jsp>').load(url)- to stay in the same page and to have the effect of overlay. thanks for the help :)